# Recompiling certain targets upon changing of dependancy using autotools

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools

I've been able to generate portable Makefiles with autotools, but I've run into an issue with recompilation of targets when I change one of the dependancies (it doesn't). Let's say I have the following code structure:

```
include -> head.h
src -> main.cpp
bin -> a.out
```

I've been able to create a makefile that will compile `main.cpp` and place `a.out` in `bin`. It should be noted that `main.cpp` depends on `head.h`. The problem I'm having is that if I change `head.h`, I need it to recompile `main.cpp` and relink to form `a.out`, and it doesn't. Traditionally I'm able to do this in a hand-made Makefile by added dependancies to each target (`main.o, a.out`, etc). This problem continues even if I change `main.cpp` (i.e. if I change `main.cpp` it doesn't recompile at all).

I do have dependency tracking turned on from configure (and it picks up that `main.cpp` depends on `head.h`), but is there something else that I'm missing to get targets to recompile when important dependancies change without cleaning and recompiling everything?

Comment: What does your `Makefile.am` look like? What output do you get from `make -d` when you run it after changing `head.h` or `main.cpp` (it will be a lot)?

Comment: Did you know you can put header files in the `_SOURCES` variable?